# AssertionError: Exception not raised

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, pybuilder

I have a unittest that test that a custom exception is raised properly. But I got get a **AssertionError: InvalidLength not raised**

Below is my unit test

```
@patch('services.class_entity.validate')
@patch('services.class_entity.jsonify')
def test_should_raise_invalid_length_exception(self, mock_jsonify, mock_validate):
    mock_validate.return_value = True

    data = self.data
    data['traditional_desc'] = "Contrary to popular"
    mock_jsonify.return_value = {
        "success": False,
        "results": {
            "message": "Invalid value for traditional_desc"
        }
    }

    with self.assertRaises(InvalidLength) as cm:
        BenefitTemplateService.create(data)
```

And this is the function I'm testing

```
class BenefitTemplateService(object):

    @staticmethod
    def create(params):

        try:
            required_fields = ['company_id', 'name', 'behavior', 'benefit_type']
            valid = is_subset(params, required_fields)

            if not valid:
                raise MissingParameter

            if not validate_string(params['traditional_desc'], 0, 1000, characters_supported="ascii"):
                raise InvalidLength(400, "Invalid value for traditional_desc")

            # Call create here
            response = BenefitTemplateEntityManager.create_template(params)
            return response

        except InvalidLength as e:
            response = {
                "success": False,
                "results": {
                    "message": e.message
                }
            }

            return jsonify(response), e.code
```

The **except InvalidLength** is working properly because if I try to do a print it execute that line of code. So I assumed that InvalidLength Exception is being called but I'm not sure on the result of my unittest it fails. Can you help please

Answer (score 1):

`create` raises `InvalidLength` exception but then catches it and handles it silently, where your test expects it to actually raise it.

Use a different assert than `assertRaises`. The `except` block returns a json, so your test can check the json's content.

Comment: How do I go around this? I need my test to tell me that an exception really was raised. I can fix this if I remove the except code but I will loose the flexibility of my response

Comment: @MadzmarUllang Then use a different assert than `assertRaises`. You return a json, so your test can check the json's content.

Answer (score 0):

you are raising the exception properly

```
if not validate_string(params['traditional_desc'], 0, 1000, characters_supported="ascii"):
    raise InvalidLength(400, "Invalid value for traditional_desc")
```

Then you catch it and return a json

```
except InvalidLength as e:
    response = {
        "success": False,
        "results": {
            "message": e.message
        }
    }

    return jsonify(response), e.code
```

hence exception does not propagate to the test.

2 ways to solve this:

- In your test, check if the json response was correct. "Invalid value for traditional_desc"
- OR Don't catch `InvalidLength` exception in your code.

I think considering your use case, you should update your test to check if the response message is correct or not.

Comment: I think the first option is more suitable in my situation as I don't want to remove my catch code.